# How to fix RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4, junit-ee

While running Junit test case I'm getting **bad RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations attribute:** error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem when using maven-compiler-plugin 3.0.
Stepping back to v2.5.1 solved the issue for me (using Maven 3.0.4)